# msp430 timer interrupts for wirting a delay method

Tags: c, msp430

What is wrong with the following code, as it does not work as expected

```
#include <msp430.h>

void initTimer_A(void);
void delayMS(int msecs);

unsigned int OFCount;

int main(void)
{
        WDTCTL = WDTPW + WDTHOLD; //Stop watchdog    timer
        P1DIR |= BIT0; //Configure P1.0 as Output

//Set MCLK = SMCLK = 1MHz
BCSCTL1 = CALBC1_1MHZ;
DCOCTL = CALDCO_1MHZ;

initTimer_A();
_enable_interrupt();

while(1)
{
    P1OUT |= BIT0; //Drive P1.0 HIGH - LED1 ON
    delayMS(500); //Wait 0.5 Secs

    P1OUT &= ~BIT0; //Drive P1.0 LOW - LED1 OFF
    delayMS(500); //Wait 0.5 Secs
        }
  }
```

initializing the inittimer_A A, seems to be not functioning according to my knowledge

```
void initTimer_A(void)
 {
    //Timer0_A3 Configuration
    TACCR0 = 0; //Initially, Stop the Timer
TACCTL0 |= CCIE; //Enable interrupt for   CCR0.
TACTL = TASSEL_2 + ID_0 + MC_1; //Select SMCLK, SMCLK/1, Up Mode
   }

   void delayMS(int msecs)
    {
OFCount = 0; //Reset Over-Flow counter
TACCR0 = 1000-1; //Start Timer, Compare   value for Up Mode to get 1ms delay per loop
//Total count = TACCR0 + 1. Hence we need   to subtract 1.

   while(i<=msecs);

   TACCR0 = 0; //Stop Timer
}

  //Timer ISR
  #pragma vector = TIMER0_A0_VECTOR
  __interrupt void Timer_A_CCR0_ISR(void)
   {
OFCount++; //Increment Over-Flow Counter
    }
```

Once the delays are introduced as normal way as delay_cycle()  program work without any error, very much appreciated if someone can correct the code..…….

Comment: Duplicate of [msp430 timer interrupts and port interrupts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61563418/msp430-timer-interrupts-and-port-interrupts)

Comment: the posted code, while in the interrupt handler function, before exiting, need to clear the interrupt flag, otherwise the interrupt handler will be immediately triggered again

Comment: regarding: `while(i<=msecs);`  nothing in the posted code is incrementing the variable: `i`

Comment: What time interval are you setting the timer before a timer overflow occurs.?

Comment: How fast are you setting the timer to count?

Comment: What value are you setting into the timer for the 'automatic' reload value?

Comment: sorry, replaced I with OFCount …….automatic reload value is the default 0xffff